# How can I make sure PHP json_encode will encode whatever data I read from the db?

Tags: php, mysql, json, character-encoding

Saving data via PHP 5.5 on WAMP to MySQL saves fine.

Recalling it to the client via json_encode did work until I dropped and entered new data into my db. Then json_encode returned `nothing` - no error - no data. No error in log file.

New data has **German street names** (with umlauts etc)

I replaced German street names with ascii codes.

json_encode worked as I expected, thus problem sort of resolved.

How does one resolve the issue going forward?

Data in my MySQL INNODB is saved as latin1.

Do I need to filter the data after read from DB, before calling json_encode ? Some other way?

Comment: use utf8 instead of latin1 in db ... if you mixed up codings you have to use uft8_decode utf8_encode etc .... to prepeare data

Comment: @donald123 I think you might be right... I just found this article from 2010 and comments from Matteo were leading me in the direction you have suggested.

I don't know how to give you a "+1" but I do think you are right. Thanks for the prompt reply!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466259/how-to-retrieve-utf-8-data-with-php-and-show-the-correct-encoding-in-an-excelshe and

Comment: [Docs](http://php.net/json_encode) mention two things: 1) input needs to be UTF-8 2) Returns `FALSE` on failure — I suspect you just plugged the function into your code, see it didn't crash the site badly and assumed you were done ;-P

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279 -- If that is not sufficient, please provide an example, together with `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM table WHERE ...` to see whether it was even stored correctly.

Comment: `äöü`:  hex for latin1:  `E4 F6 FC`; hex for utf8:  `C3A4 C3B6 C3BC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Before sql query,

And use below for json encode:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Comment: I just gave you the +1 but it says I'm too new around here for it to be made public.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course, a partial switch to UTF-8 in an existing Latin-1 site can break other things if used without actually knowing what it means.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad Sorry for the delay in accepting your solution as it works very well. Thanks again!